# Calculate per minute averages from data by seconds

Tags: excel, datetime, average, pivot-table

I have three columns, for example:

```
   A              B           C
 COUNT   TIMESTAMP           TYPE
     1   2014-12-01-00.00.01   A
     8   2014-12-01-00.00.01   B
     3   2014-12-01-00.00.02   A
    78   2014-12-01-00.00.02   C
    12   2014-12-01-00.00.02   A
```

and so on for the full day (i.e. 1st Dec 2014).

For all `TYPE` I need to calculate average `COUNT`on a 'per minute' (from `TIMESTAMP`) basis.

Is there a way to do it?

The problem is that in column B there is no fixed pattern i.e. there could be missing seconds as well. I have used PivotTables/Charts to get the data I want but I need to do per minute average analysis as well and not just per seconds.

Answer (score -1):

Could you create a third column which has the timestamp without the seconds?

Then you could use a pivot table in the same way that you did for the seconds analysis.